# Wrong assemblies being deployed in ASP.NET Core 5

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019, telerik-reporting

I am currently attempting to deploy my ASP.NET Core application, which includes Telerik reporting assemblies. For some reason, the publish target ends up with an earlier version of the Telerik. Reporting assemblies, in this case 15.0.21.224, instead of version 15.1.21.512.

How can I get it to deploy the right version. What am I missing?

Comment: What version does your csproj file show ?

Comment: It shows 15.1.21.512

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I solved the problem by deleting the obj and bin folders, cleaning the app and then re-publishing. The correct versions of the dlls are now there.